# Issues bit shifting UInt8 after converting to from Objective C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting, bit-manipulation

I am streaming video to a UIImage in my app using `NSURLConnection`. Part of my code, that works in Objective C I am having trouble converting to Swift:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {

    //...other code

    UInt32  sizeOfJPEG_1; //same type as was in Objective C

    var payloadsize = [UInt8](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0x00) //was uint8_t in Objective C
    data.getBytes(&payloadsize[1], range: NSMakeRange(12, 3))
    payloadsize[0] = 0 
    sizeOfJPEG_1 = (payloadsize[1] << 16) + (payloadsize[2] << 8) + payloadsize[3]//here is the problem
    //UInt32(sizeOfJPEG_1 = (payloadsize[1] << 16) + (payloadsize[2] << 8) + payloadsize[3]) //the way I am currently dealing with converting my shifting and additions to the correct sizeOfJPEG_1 UInt32 argument type
    //..more code
}
```

I am having two issues here:

1. I am not sure of the best way to convert the payloadsize UInt8 bitshifting and additions to the argument UInt32
   [image]
2. More importantly, possibly, to figure out first, is the runtime error I get shifting a UInt8 << 16, in objective C the type was uint8_t, I do not know if that was a legal operation in Objective C with a tyupe of uint8_t and just is not in Swift with a type of UInt8

I am getting an overflow error because I am left shifting a UInt8 << 16 as well as UInt8 << 8:
**fatal error: shift amount is larger than type size in bits**

[image]

I think I understand Objective C will quietly shift a uint8_t << 16 without crashing but I do not know how to calculate this, what is the result of uint8_t << 16, wouldn't it be 0? (*uint8_t is defined as unsigned char*)

Comment: That's a basic Swift feature. Download the Swift books and read them. Unless your variable is 0, shifting by 16 bit positions will overflow.

Comment: @gnasher729: That is not quite right. The Swift books states: “Any bits that are moved beyond the bounds of the integer’s storage are discarded.” The only restriction is that the shift amount must be less than the number of bits in the corresponding data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike (Objective-)C, Swift does not promote smaller integer types
to `int` or `unsigned int`, so you have to do that explicitly (*before*
shifting the data):

```
let sizeOfJPEG_1 = UInt32(payloadsize[1]) << 16 + UInt32(payloadsize[2]) << 8 + UInt32(payloadsize[3])
```